# Disable SelectAll and DeselectAll from Bootstrap-Select

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I am using the following configuration for bootstrap-select. I want to disable the selectAll and DeselectAll.

```
<select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" multiple data-actions-box="true" title="Choose">
   <option data-content="<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--success kt-badge--inline kt-badge--rounded'>Relish</span>">
      Mustard
   </option>
   <option data-content="<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--warning kt-badge--inline kt-badge--rounded'>Ketchup</span>">
      Ketchup
   </option>
   <option data-content="<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--brand kt-badge--inline kt-badge--rounded'>Relish</span>">
      Relish
   </option>
   <option data-content="<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--danger kt-badge--inline kt-badge--rounded'>Chili</span>">
      Chili
   </option>
   <option data-content="<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--success kt-badge--inline kt-badge--rounded'>Relish</span>">
      Mustard
   </option>
   <option data-content="<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--warning kt-badge--inline kt-badge--rounded'>Ketchup</span>">
      Ketchup
   </option>
   <option data-content="<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--brand kt-badge--inline kt-badge--rounded'>Relish</span>">
      Relish
   </option>
   <option data-content="<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--danger kt-badge--inline kt-badge--rounded'>Chili</span>">
      Chili
   </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make data-action-box property false in Select tag.

```
<select data-action-box="false"></select>
```